# WPF DataGrid trigger on other cell value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PART_DataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Items}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Margin="2,25,2,2">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Language" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="False">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Language, Mode=OneWay}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding LanguagesSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                            FontSize="16"
                            IsEnabled="False">
                    <ComboBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=test }" Value="">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.Style>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Translation" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="False">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="TranslationValueTB" 
                    Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            FontSize="16" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And I want to set that first column `ComboBox` will be enabled when second `TextBox.Text` is empty, I have tried different binding methods but none of them have worked. So how can I do that?

Comment: bind a ListOfClass to your datagrid,  populate each class as if it is a row and bind the ListOfClass to your datagrid...this allows you to add a property inside the class named "IsTextEmpty"(bool) and bind the property to the IsEnabled of your column.......the reason you would do this is it allows you to specify the behavior of each row :)

Comment: Im quite sure your trigger doesnt work, because the value of the TextBox ist not **""** but its **null**. A simple Converter which checks for nullOrEmpty should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `Value` source property that the `TextBox` in the second column is bound to:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Language" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Language, Mode=OneWay}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding LanguagesSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                FontSize="16"
                                IsEnabled="False">
                <ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Also make sure that the class where the `Value` property is defined implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raises the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `Value` property.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the IsEnabled = false from combobox and do the same in the setter as follows, and do the binding as like follows,

```
<ComboBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item.Name }" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ComboBox.Style>
```

Item.Name - > this is the property you need to check